# Why can I call boost::unique_future::get many times, unlike std::future?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-thread

I know we can't call `std::future::get` many times, and we should use `std::shared_future` if we need to call it many times.

But we can call `boost::unique_future::get` many times, although there's `boost::shared_future`!

```
void test1()
{
    int i, j;

    std::future<int> fu1 = std::async([]{ return 42; });
    i = fu1.get();
    //j = fu1.get(); // error occur
    std::cout << i << std::endl;

    boost::unique_future<int> fu2 = boost::async([]{ return 43; });
    i = fu2.get();
    j = fu2.get(); // sucess...?
    std::cout << i << ' ' << j << std::endl;

    std::cin.get();
}
```

The output is:

```
42
43 43
```

I thought for a moment and then try this test code.

```
class TestCls
{
public:
    TestCls()
    {
        std::cout << "[TestCls] default constructor" << std::endl;
    }
    TestCls(const TestCls &other)
    {
        std::cout << "[TestCls] copy constructor" << std::endl;
    }
    TestCls(TestCls &&other)
    {
        std::cout << "[TestCls] move constructor" << std::endl;
    }
    TestCls &operator =(const TestCls &other)
    {
        std::cout << "[TestCls] copy assignment" << std::endl;
        return *this;
    }
    TestCls &operator =(TestCls &&other)
    {
        std::cout << "[TestCls] move assignment" << std::endl;
        return *this;
    }
};
void test2()
{
    TestCls a, b;

    std::cout << std::endl << "unique_future test begin" << std::endl;
    boost::unique_future<TestCls> fu1 = boost::async([]{ return TestCls(); });
    fu1.wait();
    std::cout << "first assignment" << std::endl;
    a = fu1.get();
    std::cout << "second assignment" << std::endl;
    b = fu1.get();
    std::cout << "unique_future test end" << std::endl;

    std::cout << std::endl << "shared_future test begin" << std::endl;
    boost::shared_future<TestCls> fu2 = boost::async([]{ return TestCls(); });
    fu2.wait();
    std::cout << "first assignment" << std::endl;
    a = fu2.get();
    std::cout << "second assignment" << std::endl;
    b = fu2.get();
    std::cout << "shared_future test end" << std::endl;

    std::cin.get();
}
```

The output is:

```
[TestCls] default constructor
[TestCls] default constructor

unique_future test begin
[TestCls] default constructor
[TestCls] move constructor
first assignment
[TestCls] move constructor
[TestCls] move assignment
second assignment
[TestCls] move constructor
[TestCls] move assignment
unique_future test end

shared_future test begin
[TestCls] default constructor
[TestCls] move constructor
first assignment
[TestCls] copy assignment
second assignment
[TestCls] copy assignment
shared_future test end
```

Although `boost::unique_future` do "move", not "copy", it is allowed to call `get` many times.. How is it possible?

(My boost version is 1.55.0, and my compiler is VC++ 2013)

---

If I do `#define BOOST_THREAD_VERSION 4`, an exception occurs at the second call of `get()`. multiple call of `get()` is undefined behavior until version 3? Or it's allowed until version 3?

Comment: what is the version of boost that you are using ?

Comment: You said "an exception occurs at the second call of get()".  What does the exception say?

Comment: @JohnZwinck um.. maybe "hey, do you call `get()` twice!!"

Answer (score 0):

From [the documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/thread/build.html#thread.build.configuration.future) it's clear that there are at least 3 macro that are playing a significant role in what you are using

```
BOOST_THREAD_VERSION
```

which sets the version of the library, even if there are breaking changes between 4 and 3, you don't seem to have a problem with that.

second macro is `BOOST_THREAD_PROVIDES_FUTURE`, this macro is a switch, no value attached, if defined it enables the "standard" futures, not the unique_futures, what you are calling `unique_future` is just a placeholder for something that is defined by this macro at compile time.

from the file `boost/thread/future.hpp`

```
#if defined BOOST_THREAD_PROVIDES_FUTURE
#define BOOST_THREAD_FUTURE future
#else
#define BOOST_THREAD_FUTURE unique_future
#endif
```

in the file `boost/thread/detail/config.hpp` you also have `BOOST_THREAD_DONT_PROVIDE_FUTURE` which is another switch for default actions

```
// PROVIDE_FUTURE
#if ! defined BOOST_THREAD_DONT_PROVIDE_FUTURE \
 && ! defined BOOST_THREAD_PROVIDES_FUTURE
#define BOOST_THREAD_PROVIDES_FUTURE
#endif
```

note the negation `!`, which means that if you define `BOOST_THREAD_DONT_PROVIDE_FUTURE` you should get "real" `unique_future` as documented by the library.

You are basically getting the default behaviour and the fact that you are using the version 4 of the library doesn't matter that much.

A side note about C++11 and beyond:

```
std::async([]{ return 42; });
```

this is bad practice in C++11 and it's undefined behaviour in C++14, you should always specify a launch policy for your `async`.

Comment: So, Which macro is related to "calling `get()` many times"..? (I think thread version is..) Btw, is it undefined behavior without launch policy in C++14?? why?? I know implementation choose appropriate launch policy in C++11..

Comment: @ikh ask yourself what happens if you just define `BOOST_THREAD_DONT_PROVIDE_FUTURE` according to what I just posted / the official docs. Learn about how to dig into this, you can't ask for everything but the answer is 1 step away from you. Apparently the default behaviour of a boost future allows the copy of the associated object; for what concerns the C++ standard, this is what the board decided to define, and I think that I share this view, it's just what the standard says.

Comment: Concerning your last line, I don't really agree with you that it's bad practice but besides that is it really UB in C++14? Do you maybe have the respective paper?

Comment: @user2485710 Ah ok, thanks. I thought they wanted to remove `std::launch::deferred | std::launch::async` completely.

Comment: @ikh the macro that govens this behavior is BOOST_THREAD_PROVIDES_FUTURE_INVALID_AFTER_GET. It is defined by default if BOOST_THREAD_VERSION>=4.