# boost::async returns only void?

Tags: c++, boost

c++ newbie here.

I've tried to initialize and set boost::unique_future variable value:

```
boost::unique_future<bool> result;
result = boost::async([this](){return false;});
```

But I've got next error on the second code string: **Error: no operator "=" matches these operands, operand types are: boost::unique_future< bool> = boost::unique_future< void>**.

And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22433209/why-can-i-call-boostunique-futureget-many-times-unlike-stdfuture) user ikh successfully did this:

`boost::unique_future<int> fu2 = boost::async([]{ return 43; });`

But I've got the same error: **Error: no operator "=" matches these operands, operand types are: boost::unique_future< int> = boost::unique_future< void>.**

Where is my mistake?

Comment: The compiler cannot deduce template arguments from lambda expressions and the way boost::async deduces the return type of the future `result_of<decay<F>::type>::type` it gets `void`. Try using `boost::async<bool ()>([] { return false; });`

Comment: `boost::async<bool()>([] { return false; });` this follows with: Error: no instance of overloaded function "boost::async" matches the argument list argument types are: (lamda []bool()->bool). `result = boost::async<bool>([] { return false; });` gave me "Error 10 error C2665: 'boost::async' : none of the 2 overloads could convert all the argument types"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you haven't define `BOOST_RESULT_OF_USE_DECLTYPE`.

```
#define BOOST_RESULT_OF_USE_DECLTYPE
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
```

Comment: That really helped, thank you, ikh ;) And where can I find more information about #define BOOST_RESULT_OF_USE_DECLTYPE and so on?

Comment: @user2890591 Well, I had the same problem, and I figured out `unique_future` use `result_of` to see functor's return type internally, and `result_of` use "adaptable functor", deprecated in C++11. It cannot be used with lamda. If you define `BOOST_RESULT_OF_USE_DECLTYPE`, `result_of` will use `decltype()`, a new feature of C++11, to see functor's return type.